# What are the drawbacks of encapsulating arguments for different cases in one object?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism, encapsulation

I'll give you an example about path finding. When you wnat to find a path, you can pick a final destination, a initial position and find the fastest way between the two, or you can just define the first position, and let the algorithm show every path you can finish, or you may want to mock this for a test and just say the final destination and assume you "teleport" to there, and so on. It's clear that the function is the same: finding a path. But the arguments may vary between implementations. I've searched a lot and found a lot of solutions: getting rid of the interface, putting all the arguments as fields in the implementation, using the visitor pattern...

But I'd like to know from you guys what is the drawback of putting every possible argument (not state) in one object (let's call it MovePreferences) and letting every implementation take what it needs. Sure, may you need another implementation that takes as argument that you didn't expect, you will need to change the MovePreferences, but it don't sound too bad, since you will only add methods to it, not refactor any existing method. Even though this MovePreferences is not an object of my domain, I'm still tempted to do it. What do you think?

(If you have a better solution to this problem, feel free to add it to your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

The question you are asking is really why have interfaces at all, no, why have any concept of context short of 'whatever I need?' I think the answers to that are pretty straightforward: programming with shared global state is easy for you, the programmer, and quickly turns into a vortex for everyone else once they have to coalesce different features, for different customers, render enhancements, etc.

Now the far other end of the spectrum is the DbC argument: every single interface must be a highly constrained contract that not only keeps the knowledge exchanged to an absolute minimum, but makes the possibility of mayhem minimal.

Frankly, this is one of the reasons why dependency injection can quickly turn into a mess: as soon as design issues like this come up, people just start injecting more 'objects,' often to get access to just one property, whose scope might not be the same as the scope of the present operation. [Different kind of nightmare.]

Unfortunately, there's almost no information in your question. Do I think it would be possible to correctly model the notion of a Route? Sure. That doesn't sound very challenging. Here are a few ideas:

Make a class called Route that has starting and ending points. Then a collection of Traversals. The idea here would be that a Route could completely ignore the notion of how someone got from point a to point b, where traversal could contain information about roads, traffic, closures, whatever. Then your mocked case could just have no Traversals inside.

Another option would be to make Route a [Composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) so that each trip is then seen as the stringing together of various segments. That's the way routes are usually presented: go 2 miles on 2 South, exit, go 3 miles east on Santa Monica Boulevard, etc. In this scenario, you could just have Routes that have no children.

Finally, you will probably need a creational pattern. Perhaps a [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). That simplifies mocking things too because you can just make a mock builder and have it construct Routes that consist of whatever you need.

The other advantage of combining the Composite and Builder is that you could make a builder that can build a new Route from an existing one by trying to improve only the troubling subsegments, e.g. it got traffic information that the 2S was slow, it could just replace that one segment and present its new route.

Comment: As I asked to other solutions, your question is valid, altough I'm not sure if you got it all. First, the information that you say is missing in the my question is right on the title: What are the drawbacks of exposing more arguments than one implementation may need. After that you modeled a route, which didn't have anything to do with my problem (neither theoretically, nor pratically, because the real problem was defining the contract for pathfinding). But anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Dude, what I meant was there was not enough information about your modeling attempts and what made you stop and ask this vast question. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example,

Say if 5 arguments are encapsulated in an object and passed on to 3 methods.

If the object undergoes change in structure, then we need to run test cases for all the 3 methods. Instead if the method accepts only the arguments they need, they need not be tested.

Only problem I see out of this is **Increase in Testing Efforts**

Secondly you will naturally violate Single Responsibility Principle(SRP) if you pass more arguments than what the method actually needs.